# How to use MATLAB Functions in Simulink during a MATLAB ADAMS FEMM cosimulation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a MATLAB ADAMS cosimulation, which works fine, but I also want
to add another part to this system. This part gets information about the position of some points in ADAMS.

I want to use this information to draw a magnetic problem in FEMM. I already wrote a MATLAB script which does all the drawing and calculation in FEMM. The script on its own works fine.

Now because ADAMS cooperates with Simulink, I changed my MATLAB script to a function, to implement it in Simulink as a MATLAB Function block
and connect it to the other part.

But I do not know how to pass on the Simulink signal that I get out of the ADAMS block to my MATLAB Function block in Simulink, so that it can be used by
the MATLAB functions (which the script called) to create a geometry in FEMM and calculate a new Force, which than is supposed to be passed to the ADAMS block.

Now I have some questions:

1. Is it even possible to run a simulation like this? Simulink would have to wait until the calculation by FEMM is finished, to pass the output values of my function to ADAMS.
2. How can I call some MATLAB Function (that out my script) out of my MATLAB Function block in Simulink. Because right now Simulink tells me that it does not know this functions.
3. How do I define the variables in my MATLAB Function block so that Simulink can use them properly?

Comment: Hi all, just a small update I already managed to get the function working ( missed one line while copying the script) and now the variables are also defined properly. But now I get a lot of errors saying either Function called failed or XXX not supported for code generation. What can I do right now do I need to use a S-Function or another simulink block? If yes, could you please tell me where I can find a good example, with defining variables, assigning data to ths variables, calling out functions and finally passing the results of this functions on as the output of my block. Thanks in advance

Comment: See documentation for coder.extrinsic to check whether you can use that for functions not supported for code generation.

Comment: Ok, thanks this already helps me a bit, but this script I am trying to convert has a lot of functions and right now I would have to add coder.extrinsic to everyone. All it does, its says Simulink to do this part in Matlab (as far as I understood). Is there a way to get Simulink to understand I would like to run a Matlab Script with the Simulink Inputs and return the Outputs again to Simulink with one command?

Comment: Would it help someone answering the question if I post my Matlab Script which calls out FEMM?

Comment: Instead of putting your entire script inside MATLAB Function block, put your script in an external function and then call that function from the block. This way you need to use extrinsic only on that function.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just was not sure, if I could do so. Finally working thanks for the support.

Comment: Good. I posted my comment as answer.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place entire script inside an external function and then call this function from MATLAB Function block using extrinsic keyword.

```
function out = matlab_function_block(in)

  coder.extrinsic('femm_fcn');
  out = zeros(size(in)); % pre-initialize out to help coder propagate
  out = femm_fcn(in);
```

This will enable MATLAB function block to call femm_fcn using MATLAB. This however will only support simulation and will not support stand alone code generation.